# Group by with SUM total quantity sold for each product for each Customer

Tags: mysql

I have a set of customers who purchase products from the same catalog numerous amount of times during a given month.

I am now trying to create a result set which would display the agent name, and for each agent name to have a list of products bought over the month, with the total sum of quantity purchased for each product per customer with it.

For example I could buy 50 x 'product a' on monday, and then 80 boxes of 'product a' and 90 x 'product b' on thursday;
in the end it would display something like this:

```
Pavan | Product a | 130
Pavan | product b | 90
Marianne | .. so on so forth
```

I have been able to get this far, creating a query that would return each and every product bought by every single customer.

I now am trying to organise the product names so that duplicate products bought accross the month would instead be accumulated together/summed up. with only one entry of product name shown with the total sum of quantity bought by the side of it.

```
SELECT a.Agent_Name, b.Order_Id, 
    b.OrderLine_ProductName, b.OrderLine_QuantitySold 
FROM Agents a 
LEFT JOIN OrderLines b ON a.Agent_Id = b.Agent_Id
```

I have tried using GROUP with SUM and it produced some funny results.

If someone could explain the logic on how to create a query that would achieve what i explained that would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT a.Agent_Name, b.Order_Id, 
    b.OrderLine_ProductName, SUM(b.OrderLine_QuantitySold)
FROM Agents a 
LEFT JOIN OrderLines b ON a.Agent_Id = b.Agent_Id
GROUP BY a.Agent_name, b.OrderLine_ProductName, b.Order_Id
```